# Creating a multi app web page

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

Is there a way with html5, css3 and javascript to create a web page that hosts multiple frames/windows each hosting a different web app.  An additional requirement is that each frame be resizable and the user should be able to close frames that don't want and to relocate any of the frames.

Comment: You can do whatever you want using these technologies. Try to implement some of those things, and post about a specific problem you come across, together with a minimal listing of the relevant code. See how to post in https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use multiple `<iframe>` elements on the page.

**For example:**

```
<!-- 

<iframe src="https://mdn-samples.mozilla.org/snippets/html/iframe-simple-contents.html" title="iframe example 1" width="400" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe> 

!-->
```

[Take a look at MDN docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

Comment: Your question could be made a bit more clear, ie have you written the web apps? Are they using a frame ie react / angular? Are they all hosted on the same domain?